# Serializing Custom types that are set from UITypeEditor at design Time

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, windows-forms-designer, uitypeeditor

Hello I have a custom genric Form, custom type, and  a UITypeEditor among with it's Form.

I'm able to set and edit list of my custom type at design time. My Issue is. after setting it, It is not serialized to to the designer.cs file.

am I missing something here?

**MyCustomForm:**

```
 public partial class MyBrowseForm<TParentEntity> : Form where TParentEntity:class
{


    private BindingList<MyBindingFields> _myBindingFieldsCollection = new BindingList<MyBindingFields>();

   [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(BdFormTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]        
    public BindingList<MyBindingFields> MyBindingFieldsCollection
    {
        get => _myBindingFieldsCollection;
        set => _myBindingFieldsCollection = value;
    }
}
```

**TypeEditor**

```
class BdFormTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {        
        var svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService))
            as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

        BindingList<MyBindingFields> bindingFieldsList = context.Instance.GetPropValue("MyBindingFieldsCollection") as BindingList<MyBindingFields>;

        var myGenericTypeProperty = context?.Instance.GetType()
        .GetProperty("MyGenericType");                         
        var genericArgument = (Type)myGenericTypeProperty.GetValue(context.Instance);
        var editorFormType = typeof(MyEditorForm<>);
        var genericArguments = new[] { genericArgument };
        var editorFormInstance = editorFormType.MakeGenericType(genericType);
        if (svc != null)
        {
            using (var f = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance))
            {                    
                ((dynamic) f).MyBindingFieldsList = bindingFieldsList;

                f.ShowDialog();
                            context.Instance.GetType().GetProperty("MyBindingFieldsCollection")?.SetValue(context.Instance, ((dynamic)f).MyBindingFieldsList); 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            using (var f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance))
            {                   
                ((dynamic)f).MyBindingFieldsList = bindingFieldsList;

                f.ShowDialog();
     context.Instance.GetType().GetProperty("MyBindingFieldsCollection")?.SetValue(context.Instance, ((dynamic)f).MyBindingFieldsList);  

            }
        }
        return value; 
    }
}
```

MyBindingFields class:

```
public class MyBindingFields
{
    private ControlTypes _ControlType;
    public ControlTypes ControlType
    {
        get => _ControlType;
        set => _ControlType = value;
    }

    //public string MyParentEntity { get; set; }
    public string BindingField { get; set; }

    public string ChildEntity { get; set; }
    public string ValueMember { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
}
```

so what happens is after I set the values and press save. 
the values are stored in, and when I click to open this window again. I have my previous record and If I add a new record it's fine as well. the issue here is that the data is not serialized to the designer.cs file because of this reason. when I run the program or clean&rebuild the solution I lose this data. 
what am I missing here? what do I have to do so that when I press the save button It serializes the data to the designer.cs?
[image]

Comment: Data can only be serialized into InitializeComponent() if it is exposed by a public property and the type has the [Serializable] attribute.  Don't over-do this, it is quite risky.  Exceptions at design-time, like the kind you'll get when you change the type, cause pretty nasty problems.  InitializeComponent() is not a very good database.

Comment: I'm only storing string values here.. even If I put the serializable attribute on top of my MyBindingFields class it still does not do the job. so any suggestions?

Comment: Here, the problem is not `Serializable` attribute. In fact you don't need to mark your model as serializable. Instead, you should use `CollectionConverter` as the type converter for the property. Also currently in your code the editor doesn't return the edited value. You should return the value which you get from the dialog, after `ShowDialog`. You need to apply a couple of changes to make the code working.

Answer (score 0):

To make `BindingList<MySampleModel>` editable using your custom editor, you need to apply these changes:

**1)** The property should be decorated by `CollectionConverter` :

```
public partial class MyBaseForm<T> : Form
{
    public MyBaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    BindingList<MySampleModel> someProperty = new BindingList<MySampleModel>();
    [Editor(typeof(MyUITypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CollectionConverter))]
    public BindingList<MySampleModel> SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set { someProperty = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Type MyGenericType { get { return typeof(MySampleModel); } }
}
```

Then for the `DerivedForm`:

```
public partial class MyDerivedForm : MyBaseForm<MySampleModel>
{
    public MyDerivedForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Note:** You *don't need* to mark `YourModel` as `Serializer`. Your model will be serialized this way:

```
MCVE.MySampleModel mySampleModel1 = new MCVE.MySampleModel();
MCVE.MySampleModel mySampleModel2 = new MCVE.MySampleModel();
...
...
mySampleModel1.Id = 1;
mySampleModel1.Name = "X";
mySampleModel1.Price = 100;
mySampleModel2.Id = 2;
mySampleModel2.Name = "Y";
mySampleModel2.Price = 200;
this.SomeProperty.Add(mySampleModel1);
this.SomeProperty.Add(mySampleModel2);
...
...
```

**2)** In the `MyEditorForm`, you should return a new instance of the `BindingList` after edit to make the designer serialize the list:

```
public partial class MyEditorForm<T> : Form
{
    public MyEditorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
    public BindingList<T> List
    {
        get
        {
            return (BindingList<T>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                value = new BindingList<T>();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<T>(value);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

**3)** In your `UITypeEditor` you should return the value after the dialog closed:

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
    var svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService))
        as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
    var myGenericTypeProperty = context.Instance.GetType()
        .GetProperty("MyGenericType");
    var genericArgument = (Type)myGenericTypeProperty.GetValue(context.Instance);
    var editorFormType = typeof(MyEditorForm<>);
    var genericArguments = new[] { genericArgument };
    var editorFormInstance = editorFormType.MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
    if (svc != null) {
        using (var f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance)) {
            f.GetType().GetProperty("List").SetValue(f, value);
            if (svc.ShowDialog(f) == DialogResult.OK)
                return ((dynamic)f).List;
        }
    }
    else {
        using (var f = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance)) {
            f.GetType().GetProperty("List").SetValue(f, value);
            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                return ((dynamic)f).List;
        }
    }
    return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
}
```

Comment: I've tested the solution with my code samples and it works properly. There is some small differences between my code examples and your code which doesn't make any change in the totality of the answer . Let me know if you have any problem applying the solution.